# How does the algorithm for the "report abuse" feature on a website work?

Tags: algorithm

I was just wondering- is there an automated way that the "report abuse" (for profane or inappropriate posts) feature works for a large website like, say, Amazon? Is it just a simple game of numbers (e.g. 100 ppl report the link so it should be taken down) or something more sophisticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a link on a website that the website-owner implemented? I don't think there is a some sort of top-down regulated method of implementing this, everyone does it's own thing. Some will be 'just simple numbers', some will be more sophisticated.

SO does both I guess: the more flags, the more a problem (spam for instance) gets attention of people who can lock, and flags of some users way heavier then others...

Comment: ack. you can do a lot here i think. `reports/views`, `reports/replies`, weighted reports ...